# Drawing a bitmap-animation doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I got the following problem with drawing an animation on a surfaceview in android:

I use a thread to make the onDraw()-method get called regulary, and i use this:

```
c.drawBitmap(pic, partOfTheImage, destination, null);
```

to draw the part of the spritesheet i want to draw.
The problem now is that altough i change "partOfTheImage", the only thing thats drawn is what was drawn first. It doesnt change, no animation.

Here is the code in the thread:

```
            try {
               c = getGw().getHolder().lockCanvas();
               synchronized (getGw().getHolder()) {
                   getGw().onDraw(c);

               }
        } finally {
               if (c != null) {
                   getGw().getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
               }
       }
```

Does anyone know why my Bitmap isnt updating?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's actually drawing? What does getGw() do? I don't think just calling onDraw() will work. Instead, you should call invalidate() on the view. Invalidate will cause the view to be redrawn at some point in the future. Android has a rich set of animation tools. Have you taken a look at them?

Comment: yep, it is called, i already tested it with logcat... but it seems like the "drawBitmap()" is only called once... And i wanted to handle the animations with code, and i already red some tutorials on that part, but their code wont work for me :?

Comment: Just because onDraw() is called doesn't mean that it is actually being put on the screen, and that's why I recommend calling invalidate instead. It's like expecting an activity to be created and work properly by calling onCreate(). It's not intended to be called that way. If drawBitmap() is only being called once, that's my best guess.

Comment: okay, the problem now is that my GameThread is not allowed to call invalidate, because its not the thread that created the surfaceview. I did it just like here: http://www.droidnova.com/2d-sprite-animation-in-android,471.html - i dont get it; did anything change since 2009 concerning this?

Comment: That's to be expected. All you have to do is run the invalidate on the ui thread. Do surfaceView.post(new Runnable(){surfaceView.invalidate();});

Comment: I can't really comment on the tutorial. I've never seen redrawing done that way.

Comment: Looking at the code, since the Canvas returned may be null and your code doesn't seem to handle this possibility, _and_ in your try/finally code you don't actually display any error message, it may be that your Thread got blown to bits by a null Canvas reference, and therefore never update the graphics again.

Comment: @Kai I dont think thats the case, thank you tough. I added a Log.d("Custom Note","draw method"); after the "drawBitmap" and it gets called often enough!

Comment: OK I am not sure what's the cause here, so can you try commenting out everything in onDraw() and add the following to see if the numbers are updated?
          `Paint paint = new Paint();`
`paint.setColor(0xFF000000); /*assuming white bg*/`
`c.drawText(System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, 0, paint);`

Comment: Okay there changed something - about 1-2 seconds after launch, the bitmap updates once, and so does the text.. but after that it stays the same.. altough the onDraw() is called ofter, the canvas doesnt update( or at least does this only once).. hmm

Comment: ok i figured out that surfaceView.post(new Runnable(){surfaceView.invalidate();}); does the trick, but it is only run once, how do i make it called regular? :?